# RPG SETLL Usage with Partial Key

Tags: rpgle

I have a task to read a header and detail tables.

Header  get the ordernumber

Detail.
Key is  ordernumber, orderline.

```
c     Keyordnum     Setll     detail
c                   Iffound
c     Keyordnum     reade     detail
c* read for each orderline update the warehouse field
c     xxxxxxx       update    detailformat
```

Problem  I am having is error for writing a duplicate record.

Question 1. Is the xxxxxx above where I can make a composite key of ordernumber and orderline and updaten this way? the issue is how to update each line.

If not this way how do you solve the issue of reading partial key and updating each line?

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` doesn't have a factor 1.  You don't use a key when using `UPDATE`.  The record updated is the last record you read.

Your code doesn't appear to be complete.  I'd expect something like so:  (written in free-format as I've not written fixed format in 10 years)

```
setll  keyordno detail;
if %found(detail);
  reade keyordno detail;
  dow not %eof(detail);
     //set warehouse field
     update detailformat;
     reade keyordno detaill;
  enddo;
endif;
```

You shouldn't be seeing duplicate records unless there is a unique key involving the warehouse field.

Comment: You might want to use `%equal` instead of `%found` if the goal is to avoid entering the read loop when the key does not exist. `%found` is `*On` when `setll` finds any record >= the key. `reade` can still return `%eof` on the first read as the loop is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

xxxxxx above as factor with update cannot have a composite key, if there is a duplicate, it is already read before the update.


so if you are not sure whether duplicate ordernumber is read from the header itself, have an additional check with a work variable (wk_ordernum) for value is changed to read again. something like this..

```
if wk_ordernum <> ordernumber; //check duplicate ordernumber
wk_ordernum = ordernumber;
setll  keyordno detail;
if %equal(detail); 
  reade keyordno detail;
  dow not %eof(detail);
     //set warehouse field
     update detailformat;
     reade keyordno detaill;
  enddo;
endif;
endif; // end check duplicate ordernumber
```